# How to enlarge the border around constraint layout in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am getting a border around a constraint layout as shown (light green border). How can I enlarge the border as shown in "RED" (attached picture) I tried padding command, but doesn't make any change. Can someone please suggest a solution. Thanks!

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewBorder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/outside_shape"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/favoriteButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/favoriteButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/eventImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/eventPerson"  />
```

Here is the code for the background shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#04C187" />

    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your border is basically coming from the background shape just change the width of the background shape stroke

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp" <!-- Change the Width Here -->
        android:color="#04C187" />

    <padding android:left="6dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: That's just making the border thicker, I like to keep the thickness same, but offset towards outside all 4 sides.

Comment: I tried to give a -value to offset, but that doesn't work...Any thoughts